# How to handle real time notification using WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, websocket, socket.io

I've made real time chat app in React.js using Socket.io as milion of them in web. So now user A and user B can talk if they have open chat. I would like to add a new feature - when user A has open chat and user B has closed chat. When user A will send the message to user B he will get a popup/notification that he has new message and when he'll click on the notification he will open the chat and see the message. 
I didn't found any solution here. Do U guys know how to solve this problem ? Is there any function in Socket.io to handle this ?

Comment: You need to look for the notification API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Answer (score 0):

This is a very **open** question. By the way I'll try to explain the main concepts of a possible solution.

First of all, you need to consider that if you want real-time notification for "background-message" client B will need to keep connection open with socket (otherwise you'll need a sort of polling logic). Since B is connected to socket you can consider to work with Socket.io namespace in order to send this notification in another "room".

Another solution can be made by using *Push Notification API* provided by **Firebase**, **AWS**, etc.